# IP address to map in /etc/hosts file on windows

Tags: docker, networking, virtual-machine, devops, hosts

I have created a VHD image for windows Hyper-V Manager. This VHD image is consisting of Linux OS, with Docker and docker-compose installations. First I've created a QEMU image on the Linux machine and then converted it to a VHD image. On the Linux machine, the IP address of VM is `192.876.165.81`. I have mapped this IP address to wildfly and virtuoso database in `/etc/hosts` file on the Linux machine.

After importing/attaching VHD image in Hyper-V manager, and starting the same VHD image, I have setup the network bridgé on Hyper-V Manager for accessing the external websites. After starting the VHD image, in command terminal running "ifconfig" command, I can see the IP address is `172.12.0.1` for that VHD image.

My question as I am able to access the wildfly and virtuoso management on the Linux machine after configuring the `192.876.165.81` in `/etc/hosts` file. Which IP address I have to configure in /etc/hosts file on Windows machine to access the wildfly and virtuoso management. `192.876.165.81` or `172.12.0.1`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The right answer to “how do I configure `/etc/hosts` in 6 different places” is usually “run a DNS service”.  SO is generally about programming questions, not system configuration like this; is there a specific way this impacts your application source code?

Comment: @DavidMaze ....... do you know the answer?